# ElastiCache Redis spikes

Tags: redis, delay, latency, amazon-elasticache

I'm using [ElastiCache Redis](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) and storing small piece of data (~5-10MB) in it. Everything works perfect for a while and then suddenly it responds lot longer than usually (like 2000ms instead of 100ms). Most of actions that I'm doing is simple select single entry from Redis and then providing it to client. I noticed this problem only in benchmarks, not in real usage.

According to Google and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384436/redis-memory-and-cpu-spikes) it can be related to Redis Persistence, but I found that **persistence is disabled** in group options of ElastiCache.

I used [redis-stat](https://github.com/junegunn/redis-stat) to monitor stuff in Redis, and seems like there are regular CPU usage spikes by system every n-minutes.
Anyone knows what kind of thing can cause such problem?

Comment: Does your SLOWLOG show anything? If it doesn't, this could very well be a noisy neighbor - which EC instance type are you using?

Comment: Slowlog len is 0, so completely nothing. EC instance seems to be m3 medium. Not sure, how can "noisy neighbor" be related to this problem, if persistence is disabled and only the RAM is used. (??)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: Nope, I ended up moving away from Redis solution. :(